# Magento Event/Observer - access event objects

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, event-observer

We listen to various explicit and implicit events dispatched in Magento and hook up methods to perform our own logic.

But the thing i have wondered is, is there a way to know what objects i am able to access in the observer method specially for some explicitly called events, rather than going and looking at where the event is dispatched.

Is there a way by which we know which objects are passed in Varien_Event_Observer param?

Comment: a simple way to do it is to call the `getData()` method which returns an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

As Alex Dinca says you can use $observer->getData() and log to print it out somewhere, however I think the best way is to use a debugger such as xDebug or Zend Debugger, set a break point in your observer and then you will be able to see what is contained within $observer.